# Iterate through a complex dictionary with python

Tags: python, django

I would like to browse this dictionary especially the **lines** sub-array

```
my_dict= {
  "alla": "koko",
  "messages": [
  {
    "env": "dlo",
    "detail": "cons"
  }
],
"commandes": [
{
  "comande_numero": "lkm02",
  "date": "14/10/2022",
  "lignes": [
    {
      "product": "mango",
      "designation": "04 pacquets of mango",
      "quantite": 14
    },
    ......
    ]
  }
 ]
}
```

I tried

```
all_product=my_dict['commandes']
for one_ligne in all_product.lignes:
    // my code
```

but i have an error,
So how to browse the rows sub-array located at the dictionary level

Comment: can you access dictionary key value in python with .key or rather access ["key"] ?

Comment: In which python version it has changed to access values this way all_product.lignes a d not this way all_product["ignes"] ?

Comment: I think this is the source of your problems.

Comment: @DariuszKrynicki The source of the problem was iterating over list like it was a dictionary. But yes, it's also wrong way to search in dictionary with `.key`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"commandes" is a list, not a dictionary, so iterate properly:

```
all_product=my_dict['commandes']
for product in all_product:
    for ligne in product["lignes"]:
        // your code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain dictionary keys to access nested items

```
all_product=my_dict['commandes'][0]
for one_ligne in all_product['lignes']:
    product = one_ligne['product']
    # my code
```

or

```
for one_ligne in my_dict['commandes'][0]['lignes']:
    product = one_ligne['product']
    # my code
```

Comment: "commandes" is a list, not a dict...

Comment: @Tsane , i have this error (list indices must be integers or slices, not str)

Comment: @Khalifa exactly what I've said.

Comment: how should I proceed?

Comment: @NixonSparrow Good catch, added the slicing for it since seems to be a single item list

Comment: @Tzane then it will iterate only over one object. There might be more later. Please, don't answer when you lack in basics of Python.

Comment: @Khalifa I have posted another answer.

Comment: @NixonSparrow In the sample data 'commandes' seems to only contain a single item, but multiple 'lignes', so adding iteration on both levels seemed unnecessary to me. Obviously if there were multiple 'commandes', you can choose to iterate over it as well.

Comment: @Tzane it's bad practice to assume that there will always be only one value in a list, especially when the key name is in plural, right? ("commandes")

Comment: @NixonSparrow I can see that, but without knowledge about the rest of code it is hard to say for certain. If all other 'commandes' also return products that we want process in the same fashion then I agree with you 100%. But if the content of 'lignes' is something else, we might want to process it differently, so iterating over everything might be unwanted. This is getting kinda speculatory, but regardless thanks for the discussion.